# WPF ComboBox delayed filtering

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, filter

Consider following situation:
there is ComboBox and a filter TextBox, then user types a text in a text box ComboBox items source is updated using filter text. Everything works, but filtering occurs on every typed letter. I want to add a delay before filtering occurs (filter is not applyed while user is typing). What is the simpliest way to do it?

Comment: I can't remember the exact timer class this minute, so not writing an answer.  But in your view model (if you're doing MVVM), you could have a data update kick off a timer rather than applying directly to the combo box.  Make sure you set it up to fire only once, and reset each time data is entered.  Set it up for, say, 500 milliseconds.  Then it will only update 500ms after the user pauses typing.  I've used this approach on a custom filesystem directory selector auto complete text box control (ala run prompt).  It worked well and was easy to make bug-free.

Comment: @Merlyn thank you, I will try this approach too.

Comment: I believe this is more or less the same as the accepted answer.  Hope it works for you.  Cheers!

Comment: @Merlyn actually after testing both approaches I found, yours to be more convenient as it doesnt require 'TimeSinceType' variable and additional checks in '*_TextChanged' method.

Comment: Oh, I see the difference.  I'll add this as an answer later today.  I'm kind of cheating because his answer reminded me of the timer class to use ;)

Comment: If you're using MVVM, see my answer below rather than doing what's discussed here. No timer is needed--just put a delay on the binding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most used way of doing this is introducing a timer where everytime the user enters a new character your timespan get's reset but if it is longer than x seconds then execute the code.

Remember to do it async so that if the user starts typing again while you are performing a search you can cancel the async call as that information will now be outdated.

If you are using a viewmodel just change textbox1_TextChanged to the appropriate Properties setter

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!tmr.Enabled)
        {
            tmr.Enabled = true;
            tmr.Start();
        }


        TimeSinceType = DateTime.Now;

    }

public DateTime TimeSinceType { get; set; }

protected void Load()
{
      tmr = new Timer();
      tmr.Interval = 200;
      tmr.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(tmr_Elapsed);
}

void tmr_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((DateTime.Now - TimeSinceType).Seconds > .5)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate()
        {
            //LoadData();
            tmr.Stop();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works just exact as I need. I replaced, however, Dispatcher.BeginInvoke with Dispatcher.Invoke. Search is fast enough, just no need to execute it while user is typing.

Comment: Do you need the dispatcher to call it?  Could you get threading errors (UI thread) if you don't have it?

Comment: Yip, If you are going to update something on the UI thread, you can actually try this fairly easily and you will see it throws an InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: @Merlyn Dispatcher is requred for correct update of WPF controls. See remarks section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx

Comment: That should be .TotalSeconds, and not .Seconds, when calculating the elapsed time delta. If you are not aware of the difference, then you risk introducing subtle bugs that can be really hard to track down.

Comment: TimeSinceType is set in textBox1_TextChanged after the timer is started. There is a risk it won't be set before it is used by the timer's handler.

Comment: In the timer's handler, DateTime.Now is used. It might be better to use e.SignalTime, for improved accuracy, and less use of resources.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done much easier now by putting a delay directly on the binding:

```
<ComboBox Text={Binding MyBinding, Delay=200} />
```