# WPF ComboBox for slow typers

Tags: wpf, combobox

In my WPF application I use a combobox.
When the user wants to select an item he can type in letters and the combobox jumps to the next entry starting with these letters. If the user stops typing and starts again after a certain delay, the combobox assumes the user has started a new word. Well that's the usual ComboBox behaviour, nothing special there...
The problem is, some of our users are slow typers. Is there a way to increase the time allowed between typing two letters without the combobox assuming the user is searching for a new word?
Hope you know what I mean...

Comment: Looks like this question has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973422/wpf-combobox-delayed-filtering

Comment: Have you considered using `IsEditable="True"`? That way the Combo doesn't restart automatically, but your users just have to enter whichever text they want to filter the items, typing and deleting as they like.

Comment: In other words, there's no built-in function to increase that time? 
@JamesHarcourt the solution in the link has a textbox for the filtering, not quite what I have but I guess it'll help figuring out the right way to solve the problem (it will probably be a bit harder not violating mvvm rules).

Comment: if I understaned it correctly the link @James Harcourt mentioned is about sth like AutoCompllete search box behaviour. this one is about simplest-default windows combobox, right?

Comment: my best guess is this is similar to windows explorer search as you type thing. But in this question still no one knows the answer : http://superuser.com/questions/909410/can-windows-explorers-search-as-you-type-speed-be-modified

Comment: I've checked what almulo suggested (actually we are using the same principle in our software) and it is working with very long delays as well. What I can thing of, is that while the user is typing, something steals focus (after that delay) and on returning the focus to the combobox, the whole text is focused. This way typing anything will remove existing text in the combobox. @sth_Weird, can you confirm that?

Comment: @Mike Unfortunately setting "IsEditable" to 'true' does not solve the problem. The default behaviour of the combobox, which is to start searching for a new word if the user doesn't type in another letter for some time, is just fine, it's just that the delay between two letters is too short for some of our users.

Comment: Use threading and invoke the control to update the listbox entries. This will keep the application from freezing. Alternatively you can add a button the user can click when they finishes typing.

Answer (score 0):

You could go full bore and roll your own filterable combo box. 
Check out this code and see if it helps any.

The XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="myComboBox" TextBoxBase.TextChanged="myComboBox_TextChanged" DisplayMemberPath="myDisplay" IsEditable="True" StaysOpenOnEdit="True" SelectionChanged="myComboBox_SelectionChanged" />
```

Then, under the hood:

```
ObservableCollection<myType> myCollection;
public ICollectionView cvs { get; set; }
public MyWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    myCollection = new ObservableCollection<myType>();
    cvs = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(myCollection);
    myComboBox.ItemsSource = cvs;
    cvs.Filter = FilterOut;
}

private void myComboBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    cvs.Refresh();
}

private bool FilterOut(object input)
{
    myType item = (myType)input;
    return ( string.IsNullOrEmpty(myComboBox.Text) || item.myDisplay.Contains(myComboBox.Text));
}
```